# Why does JS Promise .then() evaluate before resolve()

Tags: javascript, promise

I've been playing with Promises and I put together the following code that isn't acting like I'm expecting it to. You can run it in a Fiddle here:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1pmk

```js
function log(txt) {
  var lapsed = new Date().getTime() - START;
  console.log(lapsed, txt);
}
START = new Date().getTime();

var promise = new Promise(function promiseExecutor(resolve, reject) {
  log('in Promise 1 Executor');
  setTimeout(function onSetTimeout() {
    log('in Promise 1 Timeout');
    resolve(123);
  }, 500);
});

var promise2 = new Promise(function promise2Executor(resolve, reject) {
  log('in Promise 2 Executor');
  setTimeout(function onSetTimeout() {
    log('in Promise 2 Timeout');
    resolve(123);
  }, 1000);
});

// sequence
promise
  .then(promise2)
  .then(function onPromiseDone(p) {
    // TODO: why this executes before promise2 resolve?
    log('ALL Promise Done! ' + p);
  });
```

If you watch the Console, you'll notice that the "ALL Promise Done" message is fired immediately after the FIRST promise is resolved, and then half a second later the 2nd promise is resolved...

How is it possible that the final then(onPromiseDone) is fired without resolve()?

Now, I understand that the Promise executor function starts running immediately, and this here is not a good example for "sequencing". I am able to achieve the correct behavior by wrapping my promises in "deferred" functions as shown here:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1pml

Still, this doesn't answer my question for the original fiddle, which I'll repeat:

How is it possible that the final then(onPromiseDone) is fired without resolve()?

Thanks!

Comment: note that you started both promise1 and promise2 back to back, there is no sequence involved.. you mightaswell have used Promise.all

Comment: You seem to be looking for `Promise.all([promise, promise2]).then(onPromiseDone)`

Comment: 1) I addressed the "back-to-back" scenario in my post; how does that excuse the final onPromiseDone() firing without resolve()?

Comment: 2) I'm not looking to parallelize with Promise.all; I'm simply trying to understand how is it possible for "then()" chain to resolve without "resolve()" being called...

Comment: @IvanJouikov you didn't give .then a callback to call... so it just continued on. since promise1 was resolved, the second then called it's callback.

Comment: @IvanJouikov, it's as good as a noop if the arguments to `then` aren't functions.

Answer (score 1):

[`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) receives two arguments: a function that triggers when the Promise successfully resolves and a function that's invoked when the Promise is rejected (can be ommited).

In your example, you're passing a new promisse as an argument.

In order to achieve your goal (chain), I suggest something like that:

```
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  log('in Promise 1 Executor');
  setTimeout(function onSetTimeout() {
    log('in Promise 1 Timeout');
    resolve(123);
  }, 2000);
});


var callback = function(val) {
  log('received from the first promisse: ' + val)
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    log('in Promise 2 Executor');
    setTimeout(function onSetTimeout() {
      log('in Promise 2 Timeout');
      resolve(456);
    }, 2000);
  });
}


// Promise.all([promise, promise2]) // parallelize
// sequence
promise
  .then(callback)
  .then(function(val) {
        log('received from the second promisse: ' + val)
        log('ALL Promise Done! ');
    }
  );
```

This way, you run your `promisse` and set the `callback` function as `.then` parameter. So, just when the first `setTimeout` finishes, it will  call `resolve` and invoke `callback` function, that will create a new Promise and then set the new `setTimeout`.

Will output:

```
0 "in Promise 1 Executor"
2002 "in Promise 1 Timeout"
2002 "received from the first promisse: 123"
2002 "in Promise 2 Executor"
4002 "in Promise 2 Timeout"
4003 "received from the second promisse: 456"
4003 "ALL Promise Done! "
```

### Working fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/L8b8fow9/**

**Edited after @Bergi's comment. Thanks.**

Comment: Ah yes I forgot that the "then" function needs to return a promise... Essentially in my original example I can just replace the line ".then(promise2)" with ".then(function(){return promise2;})"

...such a subtle change but quite a bit of difference. Promises aren't easy! Thanks for your help!

Comment: *In my original example I can just replace the line ".then(promise2)" with ".then(function(){return promise2;})"* that's it. You're welcome!

Comment: This is a bad idea, as the timeout in `promise2 `still starts immediately not when `promise` resolves. If you want to run them sequentially, put the creation of `promise2` inside that callback; if you want to run them in parallel, use `Promise.all` to wait for them.

Comment: @Bergi you're right! I edited the answer. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: @IvanJouikov Please check the edited version of the answer, now it's behaving like expected.

Comment: is there any other way without set time out, I am experiencing the same problem